# Getting strange error after upgrading to latest android SDK and ADT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-build, android-debug

I recently upgraded to recent android SDK and ADT in eclipse.
I am on windows 7.

I am facing a strange problem - after some build and runs and debug on device, I am getting error message
 'C:\Users\hp\workspace_1\com.xxx.yyy\bin\com.xxx.yyy.apks': Access is denied

here eclipse is not able to remove the old .apk and create the new one.

when I try to delete the .apk file, I am not allowed to do that. System is not able to show its ownership. Even I try as administrator I am not able to copy, open or delete this .apk.

the only way is to copy workworkspace with a different name, in this the apk won't be copied.
But then problem repeats.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close eclipse, stop adb, delete manually the bin's content, re-open eclipse, Clean project.

That solves it for me every time.